# How to play video from a specific position?

Tags: c#, video, avi

I'm wanting to create a program that you can play an AVI file starting at a specific position, and to play for a specified amount of time.
I can't figure out how to start at a specific position. Anybody know what I should do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using MediaPlayer class to play the movie. You can start movie from a specific position by setting current position property. Here is the documentation of "position" property,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.position.aspx

Please see the list and description of other MediaPlayer functions at following link,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.aspx